# updated listitem attributes aren't commiting changes to sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

i'm uploading a document to sharepoint.. however i would like to provide a custom name rather than it inherit the name of the file which im uploading.

my code was based on this solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103503/How-to-upload-download-a-document-in-SharePoint-20.aspx

however this doesnt work.

Additionally, i would also like to provide a title of the file:
so i wanted to update the title:

```
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["Title"] = "my custom title";
```

However, once the file has completed its upload..i login to sharepoint and notice the title hasnt been applied.

how can i intergrate uploading the file and applying a new name?

many thanks,

EDIT:

```
        using (var clientContext = GetNewContext())
        {
            var uploadLocation = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", SiteUrl, Helpers.ListNames.RequestedDocuments, Path.GetFileName(document));

            //Get Document List
            var documentslist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Helpers.ListNames.RequestedDocuments);

            var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation
            {
                Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(document), //Assign to content byte[] i.e. documentStream
                Overwrite = true, //Allow owerwrite of document
                Url = uploadLocation //Upload URL,

            };

            var uploadFile = documentslist.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);

            uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["Title"] = title;

            uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();           
        }
        site.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict, true);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a call to clientContext.Load after you add the file to the Files collection. See these blog posts for more information:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/965/programmatically-upload-document-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint.aspx

https://zimmergren.net/sp-2010-uploading-files-using-the-client-om-in-sharepoint-2010/

This code sample is from the first blog post linked above:

```
public Boolean UploadDocument(String fileName, String filePath, List metaDataList)   
{  
    SP.ClientContext ctx = new SP.ClientContext("http: //yoursharepointURL");  
    Web web = ctx.Web;  
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();  
    newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C: \TestFile.doc");  
    newFile.Url = " / " + fileName;  
    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");  
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);  
    context.Load(uploadFile);  
    context.ExecuteQuery();  
    SPClient.ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;  
    //Set the metadata  
    string docTitle = string.Empty;  
    item["Title"] = docTitle;  
    item.Update();  
    context.ExecuteQuery();  
}
```

Comment: When answering a question, please add code samples to the answer.  I am having the same problem as @nologo, but both of the sites you referenced are down.

Answer (score 3):

Are you calling Update after setting the field values?

```
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of setting:

```
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["Title"] = title;
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
```

set it as follows:

```
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Title"] = title;
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
```