# ListItem Update from Client Object Model Not Triggering OnWorkflowItemChanged Activity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, workflow-activity, sharepoint-clientobject

I am experiencing difficulty creating a file in a document library using the client object model. My custom Visual Studio 2010 workflow is not detecting the updates I am making to the file's list item after it is created.

I'd like to give an idea of the infrastructure to answer some likely questions:

- The document is uploaded to a web service, which is responsible for actually inserting the document in the library and configuring the values of its list columns
- The web service is performing this operation using the Client Object Model
- The web service is authenticating against the SharePoint site with an account created for business intelligence automation that DOES NOT RUN as the system account when interacting with SharePoint; it is, however, a member of SharePoint owners
- The operations in the custom workflow depend on the file's list item columns being populated before it can proceed to assign tasks to the users in two of those columns; for that reason, I created a While activity to monitor changes in the list item until those two columns are no longer null

The following is a sample of what the web service is doing. It is running in IIS under the Business Intelligence user identity. I've added some comments as to which operations I was anticipating the workflow would respond appropriately.

```
Using client As New ClientContext(My.Settings.SharePointSiteURL)

    // Pre-processing to determine appropriate user ID values for columns

    Dim fci As New FileCreationInformation() With {
        .Content = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(storagePath),
        .Overwrite = True,
        .Url = String.Format("{0}/{1}", theList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, theFileName)
    }

    Dim theFile As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File = theList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci)

    // Expecting the workflow to be activated here
    client.ExecuteQuery()

    theFile.ListItemAllFields("Project_x0020_Manager") = pmId
    theFile.ListItemAllFields("Project_x0020_Accountant") = paId
    theFile.ListItemAllFields.Update()

    // Expecting the onWorkflowItemChanged activity to be invoked here
    client.ExecuteQuery()
End Using
```

The workflow does activate when a file is uploaded and continues on to wait for a change event from SharePoint, but that event never arrives as a direct result of the web service's operations. I'm able to modify the item manually and successfully continue on.

Is there a consideration when using the Client Object Model that might preclude these events from firing normally?

Comment: Is the problem with workflow not being triggered after putting to sleep, or the problem is that metadata are not being set via COM in this webservice? If you have second problem maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200654/updated-listitem-attributes-arent-commiting-changes-to-sharepoint ?

Comment: The COM is setting the columns correctly. The workflow is being started correctly. The problem is that the columns I set using the COM have no value in my first activity unless I place a While loop immediately after activation that waits for an OnWorkflowItemChanged activity. However, the COM's updates don't trigger that activity so the workflow does not advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like some weird race condition. I was able to partially reproduce your problem with some sample code:

```
using (var client = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Site"]))
{
    client.Load(client.Site);
    client.Load(client.Site.RootWeb);
    var list = client.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
    client.Load(list);
    client.Load(list.RootFolder);
    client.ExecuteQuery();
    var fci = new FileCreationInformation()
              {
                  Content = File.ReadAllBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["File"]),
                  Overwrite = true,
                  Url = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + "file.xml"
               };
    var file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);
    client.ExecuteQuery();

    //If following 3 lines are commented out, problem you described may or may not occur. I wasn't able to run into problems, when i loaded file and list item before.
    //client.Load(file);
    //client.Load(file.ListItemAllFields);
    //client.ExecuteQuery();

    //Problem also doesn't occur, when i put here
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 

    //If code just runs here without delay, sometimes i run into issue you described. 
    var itm = file.ListItemAllFields;
    itm["SampleColumn"] = "Test content!";
    itm.Update();
    client.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

and workflow:

```
public Workflow1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{
    var comment = "Workflow started!, item SampleColumn is: " +
    workflowProperties.Item["SampleColumn"];
    SPWorkflow.CreateHistoryEvent(workflowProperties.Web, WorkflowInstanceId, 0, workflowProperties.Web.CurrentUser, new TimeSpan(), "Update", comment, string.Empty);
}

private void onWorkflowItemChanged1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{
    var comment = "Workflow continous!, item Title is: " +                           workflowProperties.Item["SampleColumn"];
    SPWorkflow.CreateHistoryEvent(workflowProperties.Web, WorkflowInstanceId, 0, workflowProperties.Web.CurrentUser, new TimeSpan(), "Update", comment, string.Empty);
 }
```

And workflow itself

[image: Workflow screenshot]

If you had something different, please let me know. I had myself some problems with declarative workflows which were running on SharePoint library and most of the time i was not able to find nice solution.

Comment: This is effectively the same as the kind of construct I had. The only difference was that the onWorkflowItemChanged in my workflow was placed inside a While activity just to be thorough and make sure that the workflow didn't proceed until the change I detected showed that the Project Manager and Project Accountant columns were not null. The strange thing is that while the change event isn't detected, the columns are alternatively null if I try to create tasks and assign them to the users in those columns without waiting for a change event. The race results are never quite the same.

Comment: I've received similar feedback from other sources that this is a likely race condition that can't necessarily be worked around by anyone other than Microsoft. I'll move my database logic into the workflow itself so that it behaves deterministically rather than hoping to wait out the race. Going to mark this as the answer.